# Clear and refresh jQuery Chosen dropdown list

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to clear jQuery Chosen dropdown list and refresh it.

HTML:

```
<select data-placeholder="Select Picture..." class="chosen-select" style="width:250px;" id="picturegallery" tabindex="2">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="x">remove me</option>
</select>
```

When I click "Refresh" button, it should turn into this:

```
<select data-placeholder="Select Picture..." class="chosen-select" style="width:250px;" id="picturegallery" tabindex="2">
    <option value="1">test</option>
</select>
```

What I have tried:

```
$("#refreshgallery").click(function(){
    $('#picturegallery').empty();
    var newOption = $('<option value="1">test</option>');
    $('#picturegallery').append(newOption);
});
```

But I can't get it to update that dropdown list...
Some help? :)

Comment: Is your code in DOM ready?

Comment: Yes it is (too short comment, random text)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Using [**`.trigger("chosen:updated");`**](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events) you can update the options list after appending.

> **Updating Chosen Dynamically:**   *If you need to update the options in your select field and want Chosen to pick up the changes, you'll
>   need to trigger the "chosen:updated" event on the field. Chosen will
>   re-build itself based on the updated content.*

Your code:

```
$("#refreshgallery").click(function(){
        $('#picturegallery').empty(); //remove all child nodes
        var newOption = $('<option value="1">test</option>');
        $('#picturegallery').append(newOption);
        $('#picturegallery').trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
```

Comment: Yeah... .html() breaks the chosen combo.

Comment: If this doesn't work for me. try this: $('#picturegallery').trigger("liszt:updated");

Answer (score 8):

If `trigger("chosen:updated");` not working, use `.trigger("liszt:updated");` of @Nhan Tran it is working fine.

Comment: [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). In the meantime, please do not use answers to post comments.

Comment: @TimDiekmann This answer is more useful to me but you're saying he made a mistake. Here we are looking for answers not to Post and Comments unlike Facebook/Instagram/Any other social Medias. `ca Michel` => Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#idofBtn").click(function(){
        $('#idofdropdown').empty(); //remove all child nodes
        var newOption = $('<option value="1">test</option>');
        $('#idofdropdown').append(newOption);
        $('#idofdropdown').trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
```

Comment: Please take a moment and describe how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If in case `trigger("chosen:updated");` doesn't works for you. You can try `$('#ddl').trigger('change');` as in my case its work for me.

Answer (score 1):

MVC 4:

```
    function Cargar_BS(bs) {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetBienServicio", "MonitoreoAdministracion")',
                        {
                            id: bs
                        },
                        function (d) {
                            $("#txtIdItem").empty().append('<option value="">-Seleccione-</option>');
                            $.each(d, function (idx, item) {
                                jQuery("<option/>").text(item.C_DescBs).attr("value", item.C_CodBs).appendTo("#txtIdItem");
                            })
                            $('#txtIdItem').trigger("chosen:updated");
                        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I need to update selected value at each change because when I submit form, it always gets wrong values and I used multiple chosen drop downs.
Rather than updating single entries, change selector to update all drop downs.
This might help someone

```
 $(".chosen-select").chosen().change(function () {
    var item = $(this).val();
    $('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this for reload at the end of page , maybe this one help you**

```
<script>
  $(".chosen-select").chosen();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77201227/5063739

It does not worked for me too. Then i decided to assign the initiated control to a variable and rewrite sequential calls using this variable. That fixed the issues.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bs = $('#BookSets').chosen();

    function b1onclick() {
        bs.trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
   ....
```