# Chosen updated not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a chosen dropdown. I changed options content and call trigger chosen:updated but Chosen don't rebuild the dropdown. This is my updated

> ```
> <select name="shortcode" style="width: 150px; display: none;" class="chosen_select chzn-done" id="select_shortcode">
>    <option value=""></option> 
>    <option value="7183">7183</option>
>    <option value="7983">7983</option>
> </select>
> ```

And this is Chosen dropdown (It should be rebuilt and removed two last `<li>` )

```
<ul class="chzn-results">
   <li id="select_shortcode_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">7183</li>
   <li id="select_shortcode_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style="">7983</li>
   <li id="select_shortcode_chzn_o_3" class="active-result" style="">8208</li>
   <li id="select_shortcode_chzn_o_4" class="active-result" style="">8308</li>
</ul>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$('#select_shortcode_mask').change(function(){
    var shortcode_mask = $('#select_shortcode_mask').val();
    $('#select_shortcode').empty();
    var shortcode = {"7X83":["7183","7983"],"8x08":["8208","8308"]};
    $('#select_shortcode').append("<option value=''></option>");
    if(jQuery.isArray(shortcode[shortcode_mask])){
            $.each( shortcode[shortcode_mask], function( subkey, subvalue ) {
                $('#select_shortcode').append("<option value='"+subvalue+"'>"+subvalue+"</option>");
            })
    } else {
        var full_shortcode = ["7183","7983","8208","8308"];
        if(jQuery.isArray(full_shortcode)){
            $.each(full_shortcode, function( subkey, subvalue ) {
                $('#select_shortcode').append("<option value='"+subvalue+"'>"+subvalue+"</option>");
            })
        }
    }
    $("#select_shortcode").trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

SOLVED:
I use older version so it should:

```
$("#select_shortcode").trigger("liszt:updated");
```

So dump ^^

Comment: Ok, your chosen is not updated, but is the original select updated ?

Comment: Yes, my original select is updated. Feel like trigger don't run

Comment: have you check for errors in your console during change event ?

Comment: Yes, there's no error in my console, total clear. My original select changed every time event occur but feel like trigger don't run. Is it rig

Comment: My fault. It's old version. So dump @@

Comment: @Tien Hoang, you can post your answer and accept it(I mean, that you shouldn't put whole information in question's section). It will help other users and will look better and more clear. Read it [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: yep, using liszt helped. thanks

Comment: What is "liszt"?

Comment: @Vincent The trigger command, but be aware that this answer is 9 years old

Answer (score 8):

I use chosen plugin frequently, of course I run into this issue more than once.

normally use `.trigger("chosen:updated")` can solve it. But just one minute ago, this method doesn't work any more, I feel so confused, cause I use a same function in 2 js file, let's say the `a.js` and `b.js`, it works in `a.js`, but not work in `b.js`. I can't figure out why... I almost lose my mind!!!

So, I check the api again.I found the `.chosen("destroy")` , inspired me!

And I think it's the **Ultimate Solution**: destroy it and rebuild it.

```
$('.chosen').chosen("destroy").chosen();
```

Am I too loud? :p

Comment: Yes this worked for me as well I tried both .trigger("chosen:updated")
and 
.trigger("liszt:updated");
None seems to resolve.

.chosen("destroy").chosen(); this worked

Comment: wow ! This is the only thing that worked for me. I also observed that if the select tag is static and only if options are dynamically added  $("#select_shortcode").trigger("chosen:updated"); works fine, however if the whole select is dynamically constructed along with options only $('.chosen').chosen("destroy").chosen(); works. Do you know why is it so ?

Comment: Brutal.  Makes the updated event entirely useless.

Answer (score 3):

Your change function calls on change for element "#select_shortcode_mask". 
Your select list has id: "#select_shortcode"

Answer (score 1):

Code :

```
$('#test')
  .val(1)
  .trigger('liszt:update')
  .removeClass('chzn-done');

$('#test_chzn').remove();


$("#test").chosen({
  width: "220px",
  no_results_text: "test"
});
```

Comment: try to enhance your response

Answer (score 1):

My Way is this...

```
$timeout(function() {
  $('#CampSrchId').trigger('chosen:updated');
}, 1000);
```

OR

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  $('#CampSrchId').trigger('chosen:updated');
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its an Old question but none of the exact solution worked for me so I combined @Kaiyu Lee and @Jamie code which worked!

```
$('#your-select-dropdown-id').chosen("destroy").chosen(); 
$('#your-select-dropdown-id').chosen({ width: "100%" });
```

Many Thanks to both of you, and also do not forget to trigger('change'); on page load / document ready as well if your dropdown is dependent on another dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
$("select").chosen({ width: "100%" });//chosen hack
```

As when using `.trigger("chosen:updated");` this did not appear to resolve the issue. It looks hacky but works well.

Comment: In my case, I had to set the width explicitly on the select control. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of double inclusion of jQuery (one time in head and one time in footer)...
I removed the one in footer and `.trigger('chosen:updated');` works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

It does not worked for me too.
Then i decided to assign the initiated control to a variable and rewrite sequential calls using this variable. That fixed the issues.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bs = $('#BookSets').chosen();

    function b1onclick() {
        bs.trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case nothing worked because I was setting selected attribute wrong

> $(this).**attr**('selected', true);

Functional one is

> $(this).**prop**('selected', true);

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.select-chosen').chosen({width: "100%"});
```