# Inconsistent results when loading HTML snippet into select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using Ajax to load the contents of a `select`:

```
<select id = "idResultEntryMeet" class="form-control input-md" size = 1>
</select>
...
$('#idResultEntryMeet').mousedown(function() { 
   $.post("/cgi-bin/listOptions", function(data) {
      $('#idResultEntryMeet').html(data);
   });
});
```

This isn't consistent across browsers, which makes me think that there's a problem with the code:

1. IE9 never shows anything in the `select`
2. FF 27 works as expected
3. Chrome and IE11 don't show anything in the pull-down on the first
       mouse click, but will show the expected contents on the second mouse
       click. I can fix this on both browsers by pre-loading the `select`
       during the initial page load
4. Opera and Safari require a second mouse click, even with an initial preload

Any suggestions on what's wrong with this?

*EDIT*
Sorry, guess this wasn't obvious: the `select` must be dynamic. The options are constantly changing, depending on the contents of a database. The idea is that the user sees the current options when they click the pull-down on the `select`. Using a `click` (instead of `mousedown`) handler doesn't work, since the user can't then actually select anything they see in the pull-down.

And the CGI code returns an HTML snippet, containing the options. Firebug shows a correctly-formed `select` containing options on completion of the POST.

**EDIT**
The problem is that the Ajax request has to be synchronous (Sjax?) (as more-or-less suggested in the comments), to prevent interfering with whatever happens when the `select` pull-down is activated. This code works with proper browsers (and almost works in IE9), but changing `async` to `true` causes consistent problems with various browsers:

```
$('#idResultEntryMeet').mousedown(function() {
   $.ajax({
      type  : "POST",
      url   : "/cgi-bin/listOptions",
      async : false
   }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      $('#idResultEntryMeet').html(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: `data` receives html strings, e.g `<option ..>` ? It should get a json and then you use `$.append()` to each option.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - `data` can be anything, noone is forcing you to use JSON. But, if the OP posted what `data` actually is, it would be possible to answer this.

Comment: It's an HTML snippet containing the options. Firebug shows a correctly-formed select after the POST completes, with options inside it.

Comment: Mousedown on a select? Does it even get fired in IE9.

Comment: I find it interesting that this code works in FF.

Comment: @adeneo Would you print the html itself or json? When I say *should* I don't mean that is required to be JSON, but makes more sense. You know that.

Comment: @epascarello: it's `mousedown` on the pull-down. A `click` handler fails on pretty much everything; you can't select anything in the list.

Comment: Think about it, once you load it, you need to remove the event or every click action is going to fire it. Also you probably want to change it to a different event like over or enter and focus. [not everyone uses a mouse]

Comment: @epascarello: that's the whole point. It's dynamic; the options come from a changing database.

Comment: I know it is dynamic, but you are causing it to reload as the people are interacting with it....

Comment: Are these datas retrieve from database supposed to change betwwen each page load? Why can't you just fill SELECT with option from ajax request on DOM ready?

Comment: @A.Wolff: the database changes at arbirtrary times, and may change in response to user actions. The point is to stop the user having to refresh the page just to get the correct contents of the `select`.

Comment: What is happening is the browser appears to not like the fact it has to redraw the select list when active. Loading it with mousedown, focus, mouseover, mouseenter will all probably have the same issue with a race condition [aka will the response get back before the user opens the options]. You might be better off with a ping that checks for new data and tells the user there is new options and they can click that message to load the new values.

Comment: @epascarello is right. I got to the same conclusion when running a [test on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrp2n/). To [fix this](http://jsfiddle.net/wrp2n/1/) (in a quick and dirty way that should never see the light of day), I added a blur/focus when the ajax request was done. _NOTE: I only added the delay to test the AJAX locking mechanism._

Comment: @epascarello: Ok, your suggestion of the race condition got me on the right track - see the answer in my edit above. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try that (just tested on chrome):

```
$('#idResultEntryMeet').on('mousedown', function(e){
    if(!e.view) return;
    e.preventDefault();    
    var _self = this;
    $.post("/cgi-bin/listOptions", function (data) {
        $(_self).html(data);
         var mdwn = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        mdwn.initMouseEvent("mousedown", false, false, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
        _self.dispatchEvent(mdwn);
    });
});
```

[Simplified DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xj3qJ/)

**EDIT:** doesn't work on FF nor IE...

Answer (score -2):

Try change your code for:

**html**

```
<select id="idResultEntryMeet" class="form-control input-md" size="1">      
</select>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $.post("/cgi-bin/listOptions", function(data) {
     $('#idResultEntryMeet').html(data);
   });
});

$('#idResultEntryMeet').change(function() { 
   var valueSelected = $(this).val();
   alert(valueSelected);
   //Do something
});
```

**Edit:**
you need include the delegate bind with jquery for do this dinamic.

```
$('#idResultEntryMeet').bind("click", function() {
    var data = '<option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option>';
    $('#idResultEntryMeet').html(data);
});
```

And need format the return of the method some like this

Comment: Not even close to what the OP is doing.

Comment: It's just an example, to load the select using jquery "ready". It's work for me

Comment: It has to be dynamic: see clarification above.

Comment: But the only relevant difference between this and my original code is that you're binding `click`, and I was using `.mousedown`. `click` doesn't work anyway, because you can't actually select any options (see above). If I change your code to bind `mousedown`, then I get exactly the same results in Opera (haven't tried the others), ie. it still doesn't work on the first `mousedown`, and requires a second `mousedown`.

Comment: I found 2 links that would be useful
1:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148195/clear-and-refresh-jquery-chosen-dropdown-list
2:https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-refresh-a-select-box