# Chosen plugin not updating dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using  http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ in multiple mode and it dosen't seem to update after submitting. All I get is a blank input box and in the dropdown, the entry I just submitted is still there. I know the entry is getting submitted because of the json return. If I refresh the page, the entry is no longer in the dropdown and the default I use is there. Where have I gone wrong with my coding.

Many thanks

```
$("#box_rtv").val('Choose a box...').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

```html
<select data-placeholder="Choose a box..." class="chosen-select required" multiple="multiple" style="width:250px;" name="box_rtv[]" id="box_rtv">
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're triggering the event on a string with your code, as `.val()` returns a string. Try doing it separately, or in a different order while chaining:

```
$("#box_rtv").trigger("chosen:updated").val('Choose a box...');
```

(Actually, you probably don't need to call `.val()` at all.)

If that doesn't work, try deselecting all of your options programatically prior to triggering `chosen:updated`:

```
$("#box_rtv > option").prop('selected', false);
$("#box_rtv").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: No difference. still not updating. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way you're calling the `.trigger()` is wrong.

```
$("#box_rtv").val('Choose a box...').trigger("chosen:updated"); //WRONG
```

Instead simply

After appending all the values to the `select`, just trigger as mentioned below

```
$("#box_rtv").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: No difference. still not updating. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 I'm not sure how you're appending the options to the chosen, here look into this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20148252/1671639)

Comment: Praveen could you expand on what you mean by appending the options to the chosen? Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 I managed to create a sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/LUHLd/.  I hope you can understand it.

Comment: Praveen That is ok for adding an option to the select dropdown, but that is not what I am trying to do. I am adding the items dynamically and when a user selects an item is submit the item to the database and refresh or remove the item from the list. Doese that make sense? Thanks

Comment: Any further help with this please Praveen. It;s driving me nuts. Thanks

Comment: @user1533468 hmm .. it would be better if you can show the exact part of the code that you've written, so I can look into that perspective and help you..

Comment: It seems to me that chosen only updates the dropdown to a default state. It doesn't actually remove selected items from the list. Should i be looking at some other way to repopulate the dropdown? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case you remove and option these actions going right in this order:

```
$('#user_id').val(''); // to clean the select ( otherwise not refreshing correctly )
$("#user_id option[value='okmAdmin']").remove(); // remove some option element
$('#user_id').trigger("chosen:updated"); //
```